# Apache error log

Tags: apache, windows-7, localhost, сервер

Помогите, пожалуйста... ни один сервер не пашет, а точнее апач на любом сервере не пашет, что-то в венде скорее всего, но что - понять не могу.

```
[Mon Nov 26 19:14:44 2012] [warn] pid file C:/Program Files/VertrigoServ/Apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?[Mon Nov 26 19:14:44 2012] [notice] Apache/2.2.23 (Win32) PHP/5.3.18 configured -- resuming normal operations[Mon Nov 26 19:14:44 2012] [notice] Server built: Aug 24 2012 11:45:16[Mon Nov 26 19:14:44 2012] [notice] Parent: Created child process 5416[Mon Nov 26 19:14:44 2012] [notice] Child 5416: Child process is running[Mon Nov 26 19:14:44 2012] [notice] Child 5416: Acquired the start mutex.[Mon Nov 26 19:14:44 2012] [notice] Child 5416: Starting 64 worker threads.[Mon Nov 26 19:14:44 2012] [notice] Child 5416: Starting thread to listen on port 8080.[Mon Nov 26 19:14:44 2012] [notice] Child 5416: Starting thread to listen on port 8080.
```

Comment: на 8080 работает! спасибо! хоть что то! подскажите как сделать так чтобы по стандарту работало

Comment: Всё сделал! спасибо...не без вашей помощи.

Comment: в файле httpd.conf поменял строку "Listen 8080" на "Listen 80"

Comment: @kushren, в таком случае принимайте ответ:-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Он же запускается, судя по логам.

http://127.0.0.1:8080 не работает? Если нет, проверьте исключения в фаерволе.

Answer (score 1):

Остановите апач, проверьте файл

```
C:/Program Files/VertrigoServ/Apache/logs/httpd.pid
```

Если есть удалите, запустите.

Comment: Сделал... не помогло.

Comment: Текущий лог покажите...

Comment: Всё тоже самое изменился только "Child 5416" на "Child 1576", но он всегда меняется.